# unity get child data

Tags: class, unity-game-engine

I am trying to create a procedural created dungeon in Unity.
I have it creating the dungeon, and have a script attached to each prefab that goes to make up the walls, floor etc. Each one of these is attached to a single parent, to make it easy to delete and rebuild the entire dungeon. The script contains details:

```
 public class WallPrefab
 {
     public bool use;
     private int roomId;
     public WallTypes type; //enum = torch, switch, item etc
     public WallDirections direction; //direction wall is facing
     public GameObject myPrefab; //nested
 }
```

The prefab also contains an empty game object used as a mount point for torches, switches etc.

```
 myPrefab
      prefab //prefab for the actual 3d object
      wallmount //empty game object to store location and rotation details
      ....
```

My questions:
1. How do I get the wall type?

```
    int childs = transform.childCount;
    for (var i = childs - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        c = transform.GetChild(i).gameObject;
        Debug.Log("child:" + c.name);
        //WallTypes g = c.GetComponentInChildren<WallPrefab>().type;
        WallTypes g = c.transform.GetComponentInChildren<WallSettings>().type;
```

(Edited to insert working solution to this part of my problem!)
This code does not work, because Unity complains that:

> ArgumentException: GetComponent requires that the requested component
>   'WallPrefab' derives from MonoBehaviour or Component or is an
>   interface.

2. How do I get the transform of the mount point?

I know how to get the location and rotation, once I get the mount point, but how do I actually get the mount point?

Comment: The error you have is self explanatory, it is a standard c# class, not one derived from monobehavior so cannot be a component on a unity object.  After `public class WallPrefab` put `: MonoBehavior`

Comment: WallTypes WallType = c.transform.GetComponentInChildren<WallSettings>().type;
Works!

Comment: If you made WallPrefab (which is an odd classname) to MonoBehavior, you would be able to get the transforms of all the children.

Answer (score 1):

Question 1 seems pretty self explainatory.

Question 2 looks a bit more interessting.

If i understood you correctly, you have a script, that "creates" torches on specified mount points. Assuming those mount points are empty game objects and you dont want to add torches directly into the prefab (would be nice if we got a little bit more detail here on how exactly your dungeon+mount point is generated), i would add a script to the prefab, add a GameObject instance variable and use the inspector to drag the mount point onto the script. then i would use "gameobjectVariable.transform.position" to get the position.

something like:

```
public class prefabClassWithMountPoints{
    GameObject mountpoint; //drag mount point from inspector
    GameObject torchGameObject; //drag torch prefab here

    public void createTorch(){
        GameObject torchObject = Instantiate(torchGameObject, mountpoint.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        //...
    }
    //rest of code
}
```

this is assuming the mount points are not randomly generated WITHIN the prefab.

Comment: No, the mount points are added to the parent prefab. They are just an added empty game object, added to a parent prefab at design time. The parent prefab is generated via script. It is placed in game, and already having the mount point, it should be in the right place to be able to get the position and rotation from the empty game object. I know how to get that from a prefab. What I am having trouble with, is getting the empty game object inside the prefab?

Comment: so the mount points are added via script to a parent, that is generated via script?

Comment: No, they are not added via script. They are added to the prefab at design time, not at run time!

Comment: oh my bad. in that case you can do exactly what i described there. at design time, use the inspector to add them to a corresponding script.

Comment: What I need is a way to get a pointer to the mount points that are inside the prefab

Comment: How do you get a prefab, that is inside a prefab via script?

Comment: ok i get it now. i believe i had a similar problem before so i may be able to give you a good example later on. there are multiple ways of doing this. one of them is just to call "transform.getChild()". the other would be to redesign your prefab in a way that allows for a simpler solution

Comment: There is several prefabs inside the parent prefab, is the getchild index the offset to each one?

Comment: i believe so. according to the unity api https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.GetChild.html